# Android Emulator closed because of an internal error on macos big sur

Tags: android

When I run the emulator with NEXUS 4 api 30 I got the following error

> Android Emulator closed because of an internal error:
> emuglConfig_init: blacklisted=O has_guest_renderer=l, mode:
> swiftshader _indirect,option: (null) emuglConfig_init: GPU emulation
> enabled using •swiftshader _indirect' mode Deciding if
> GLDirectMem/Vulkan should be enabled. Selected renderer: 8 API level:
> 30 host GPIJ blacklisted? 1 Swiftshader selecte4enabling Vulkan.
> Enabling GLDirectMem Enabling Vulkan Adding to the library search
> path: /Users/rundeyang/LibrarV
> Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader

I checked the AVD manager setting, it is set to software as the renderer. I am running on MACOS big sur 11.4.